# How to call a group of scripts in a folder with `import`?

Tags: python, import, python-import

In my directory named `A`, I have 5 `.py` files that I wrote.
I want to do `import A` (or similar) to access the objects and classes from those 5 `.py` files, but I am not sure how to make this happen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create an (empty) `__init__.py` file in your directory.

See the [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) documentation:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I have placed my 5 .py files and the new __init__.py files in a single directory. What is the next step?

Comment: @jschnieder: What you ask in your follow-on question is in the linked documentation under [6.4. Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) — suggest you reading it.